# Django "Join" and "count" - Easy in psql, not so trivial in Django

Tags: django, django-models

user id  `8a0615d2-b123-4714-b76e-a9607a518979` has many entries in `mylog` table. each with an `ip_id` field. I'd like to see a weighted list of these `ip_id` fields.

in sql i use:

```
select distinct(ip_id), count(ip_id) from mylog
where user_id = '8a0615d2-b123-4714-b76e-a9607a518979'
group by ip_id
```

this gets me:

```
ip_id                                  count
--------------------------------------+--------
84285515-0855-41f4-91fb-bcae6bf840a2  | 187
fc212052-71e3-4489-86ff-eb71b73c54d9  | 102
687ab635-1ec9-4c0a-acf1-3a20d0550b7f  | 84
26d76a90-df12-4fb7-8f9e-a5f9af933706  | 18
389a4ae4-1822-40d2-a4cb-ab4880df6444  | 10
b5438f47-0f3a-428b-acc4-1eb9eae13c9e  | 3
```

Now I am trying to get to the same result in django. It's surprisingly elusive.

Getting the user:

```
u = User.objects.get(id='8a0615d2-b123-4714-b76e-a9607a518979') #this works fine.
```

I tried:

```
logs = MyLog.objects.filter(Q(user=u) & Q(ip__isnull=False)).values('ip').annotate(total=Count('ip', distinct=True))
```

I am getting 6 rows in `logs` which is fine, but the `count` is always `6`, not the weight of the unique ip as it is in the SQL response above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mistaken about what the keyword argument `distinct` does in the `Count` function. It simply means you want to count only the distinct values (you actually don't want to do that). In fact the part in your SQL query `distinct(ip_id)` is also redundant as you are going to use the `group by` clause on that anyway.

Furthermore you write `.value('ip')` which is a typo and should be `.values('ip')`.

So your ORM query should be:

```py
logs = MyLog.objects.filter(Q(user=u) & Q(ip__isnull=False)).values('ip').annotate(total=Count('ip'))
```